# How best to DRY will_paginate options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

I have 8 controllers using will_paginate to paginate their index pages.  I'd like to override the defaults for "Previous" and "Next" on each without having to specify the same options 8 times.  Is there a way to override the defaults only once (perhaps by subclassing will_paginate).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[will_paginate uses I18n](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/master/lib/will_paginate/locale/en.yml) so you can just use that.
Given you use English as the default locale the following line should be present in `application.rb`:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

you can then change the text of the pagination links by adding the following to `config/locales/will_paginate.en.yml`:

```
en:
  will_paginate:
    previous_label: "&#8592; go back"
    next_label: "go forward &#8594;"
```

Alternatively you can add them to your default translations file: `config/locales/en.yml`
but I have found that it quickly becomes to large to handle.

Note: If you use another locale, for instance `es`, for this to work you need to at least replace the `en:` keys within the YAML files to `es:` and to be concise about naming your files,
use either `config/locales/will_paginate.es.yml` or `config/locales/es.yml`.

Comment: So can we consider this question answered?

Comment: @mislav This made sense, but when I tried it (both yml files), it did not work. I'm using version 3.0.pre2 - could that be why?

Comment: Just to be sure, you are using English as the default rails locale (I believe its the default default locale :-p )? I've updated my answer to include why it might not work if you did not.

Comment: @jack: that version is too old. Please use 3.0.0 or later

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're doing something like this in your controllers:

```
will_paginate @collection, :previous_label => '< go back', :next_label => 'go forward >'
```

Your problem is that you want to use these labels everywhere in your application, so it's pointless to repeat them. In that case, you could define a helper like this:

```
def paginate(collection, options = {})
  defaults = {
    :previous_label => '< go back',
    :next_label     => 'go forward >',
  }
  options = defaults.merge(options)

  will_paginate collection, options
end
```

After that, calling `paginate @collection` in your views will use your defaults and still let you override them if necessary.

EDIT: suweller's response is definitely the better way to go in this case, especially considering it's approved by mislav, the plugin creator :). I'd completely forgotten about the translation file option. My solution could probably be useful in the general case, when the helper is not configurable in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, however, your approach would be nice if you want more than one 'default' pagination style on your site,

Comment: This simple wrapper approach is useful if you want to change the options based on any other dynamic criteria. For example, if you want different pagination options for mobile devices.