# The atrr "page_gap" of will_paginate useless?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, will-paginate

Following the code,

```
<%= will_paginate @bls, :container => false, :previous_label => "上一页", :next_label => "下一页", :page_gap => "......", :inner_window => 0, :outer_window => 0 %>
```

Everything (like previous_label) except "page_gap" helps, the gap on the page is not "......" but is "Page gap". I use the version 3.0.2(the lastest).

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/pull/213
If there is a customized page gap, it should be used instead of the default one.

**Update:**
Just try use config file. It's very useful. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7073789/how-best-to-dry-will-paginate-options)